# XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. xml to html using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am facing issue while trying to convert xml to html using xslt.
following is the dummy code i am using to parse

```
**TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xslDoc = new StreamSource( xsltPath );
            Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource( xmlPath );
            oFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream( htmlOutputPath );
            htmlFile = oFileOutputStream;
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer( xslDoc );
            transformer.transform( xmlDoc, new StreamResult( htmlFile ) );**
```

getting error as follow

ERROR:  'XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.'|#]
Any idea

Comment: Please provide us with xml and xsl code you are working with .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have closed the stream while transformer is still doing the work. Please check that you have not closed any stream resources.